# Delete an element from array using redux

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a todo app using redux and I'm stack on how to delete a todo from the array.

**reducer.js**

```
export default function todo(state, action) {
switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_TODO':
    return [
      ...state,

      {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
  case 'REMOVE_TODO':
    return {
      id: action.id,
      ...state.slice(id, 1)
    }
  default:
    return state;
 }
}
```

**action.js**

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
})

export const removeTodo = id => {
  type: 'REMOVE_TODO',
  id
}
```

So far i can add and toggle a todo as completed or not. Thanks

Comment: Is the initialState an array of todos ?

Comment: No, the initialState is an empty array.

Comment: ok so the @Pavel answer is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using redux you need to return all array elements except the removed one from reducer.

Personally, I prefer using the `filter` method of the Array. It'll return you a shallow copy of `state` array that matches particular condition.

```
case 'REMOVE_TODO':
return state.filter(({id}) => id !== action.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

In react redux application, you should know, you always have to create a new object,
to deleting an item please use spread operator like this :

```
return [...state.filter(a=>a.id !== id)]
```

Comment: You don't need to use spread operator since `Array.prototype.filter` method returns new array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: The above is useful when you have to maintain the empty array after filtering/eliminating the last item.